# What word means the opposite of "preamble"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word the describes the concluding text of a document, i.e. the opposite of the document's preamble. Is it just "conclusion"?

Comment: [A thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/preamble) gives  addendum, epilogue, postscript.

Comment: "ending" was also a good choice.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Conclusion, afterword, and epilogue all seem to fit the bill.

There's also postamble, but I believe that's more of a computer science term for data transactions.

Comment: +1 for *afterword*, which I think most accurately signifies a final section contrasted to a *preamble* before the main body of text. *Conclusion* suggests the other side of *introduction*, and *epilogue* seems much the same to me. +1 more if I could for pointing out *postamble* is really just an IT term.

Comment: Your other suggestions definitely fit better in a non-IT situation, but as it stands, I'm asking out of curiosity stemming from an IT situation. Ultimately, I think I'm going to go with "postamble". Thanks.

Comment: Clearly, the proper pairings are prologue/epilogue, introduction/conclusion, foreword/afterword, preamble/postamble, prelude/postlude, and overture/coda.

Comment: Sadly, "postamble" does not seem to be in any dictionary I looked at, nor does it seem to be used by ... anyone. And it seems like such a good word, too.